# where to put hibernate.dialect.storage_engine property

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I use `MySQL5Dialect` to replace `MySQL5InnoDBDialect` because old one is deprecated.

```
package org.hibernate.dialect;

/** A Dialect for MySQL 5 using InnoDB engine
 *
 * @author Gavin King,
 * @author Scott Marlow
 * @deprecated Use "hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb" 
environment variable or JVM system property instead.
 */
@Deprecated
public class MySQL5InnoDBDialect extends MySQL5Dialect {

@Override
protected MySQLStorageEngine getDefaultMySQLStorageEngine() {
    return InnoDBStorageEngine.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml is：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate 
Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect.storage_engine">innodb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Sadly, Hibernate still create table using `engine=MyISAM`!

Where should I put `hibernate.dialect.storage_engine` property and I could not found all properties of `hibernate.cfg.xml` from official pages! It is disturbing!

Any effective link will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [HHH Issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11610) you either should set the environment or JVM variable for this to work if you want to stick to the `MySQL5Dialect`.

Alternatively you can switch to MySQL55Dialect which has `innoDb` as a default:

```
public class MySQL55Dialect extends MySQL5Dialect {

        @Override
        protected MySQLStorageEngine getDefaultMySQLStorageEngine() {
                return InnoDBStorageEngine.INSTANCE;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set property **hibernate.dialect** in your xml configuration file to **MySQL5Dialect**

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
```

and then set JVM option **hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb** for your application. In case of runnable jar it will be something like:

```
java -Xmx4G -Dhibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb -jar application.jar
```

Or in case of some web application container (e.g. Tomcat) add

```
-Dhibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb
```

to configuration of the container/web server.